# Automate dev container creation in Visual Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

How can I integrate reading from this repo into Visual Code? I am looking to select the template from the drop list, but it seems not to show up as below from this reference https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/devcontainers/create-dev-container

[image]